# Build Modal Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, modal-dialog, avgrund

How can I run the modal and build the modal from dynamically create elements.

Example, I have a button that I want to launch the modal, which is dynamically created.

I'm using this modal plugin:
http://labs.voronianski.com/jquery.avgrund.js/

I have tried this, it does work, although it doesn't work until the 2ND click of the button.

```
$('body').on('click','#siteSwitch', function(){
        $(this).boxModal({
            height: 800,
            width: 800,
            holderClass: 'boxModal',
            showClose: true,
            showCloseText: 'X',
            enableStackAnimation: false,
            template: '<p>So implement your design and place content here! If you want to close modal, please hit "Esc", click somewhere on the screen or use special button.</p>'     
        });        
    });
```

Thankyou

Comment: Have you tried initializing it on document ready, then using the same code you use now?

Comment: Sorry, It's in document ready at the moment.

Comment: Ah, okey. Then I meant add `$(this).boxModal();` on the line before your current one. Maybe it needs to be initizalized before it can be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer guys,

It seems adding `openOnEvent: false` as an option for the modal fixes it. It makes complete sense, by default it was true, so it's waiting for a 'click' event to fire the launch which hasn't happened until it's built once in the background.

Thanks!

Shannon

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).avgrund({})
```

code is like this, rather than boxModal()